# How to read comma file (.csv) and tab separated file(.txt) by a single Flat File Source SSIS Data Flow Item?

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm new to SSIS and in one of my project I need to read both comma separated file (.csv) and tab separated file (.txt) by a single Flat File Source. Unfortunately I cannot make .txt file content as comma separated because this is how it is generated by a separate source file providing system neither have an option to modify the file content before supply to SSIS. I'm expecting some help and support of your experience.

Comment: If it is possible to use multiple Flat File Source item (say, one for .txt and other for .csv) please suggest.

Comment: It is entirely possible. You create two sources. Now how do you want to combine them? Possibly you might want to use the UNION ALL transformation - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141020.aspx

Comment: @ElectricLlama Actually my problem is a bit different. Let me make this more clear. say, I have a folder which is my flat file source to SSIS. The 1st scenario is such as I create a comma separated file in the folder and now I run my SSIS and is gonna read the file from the source and performs require task. Again in other scenario say I create a tab separated file in that same folder and now I want my SSIS does the same as it did with comma separated file(like no error reading tab separated file).

Comment: One way to do this is still create two data flows, but detect beforehand whether it is a tab or comma separated file then run the appropriate data flow. Do you have any indicator of this? Do the file have a fixed number of columns? You could open the file beforehand and check. Another way is to a do a search and replace tab with commas beforehand. I suggest you do not try and use the same source for different types of files. SSIS does not like metadata being changed on the fly.

Comment: Not a simple way to do this. I agree with @ElectricLlama, two data flows is a good solution. Other solution could be reading the rows as a single column and then separate them in a script transformation.

Comment: as per @Jayvee 's description, here's a handy script that splits one column into multiple columns based on a delimiter. You still need to work out beforehand what the delimiter is though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487988/ssis-is-there-a-data-flow-source-component-that-will-handle-csv-files-where-th?rq=1

Comment: At the risk of additional IO operations, you could add a script task to modify and save the file with another separator to replace both commas and tabs.